# Prevent slow calculate conditions from firing when the form is opened

Tags: commcare

I have a lot of calculate conditions in my form in hidden values, but they are only necessary to evaluate if the question "food_not_in_list" = 'yes'.  These calculates are slowing down my form because they fire when it's opened.  Can I either:

1. Add display condition to those hidden values so they won't calculate?
2. Wrap them in an if statement that checks the condition ... e.g. Calculate condition =  if(food_not_in_list != 'yes', '', do-the-big-calculate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the hairy part about declarative logic is that it can be a bit tough to decide when processing happens!

To answer your questions:

- A hidden value's display condition being `false` does **not** prevent the hidden value's calculation from executing. All calculations are performed regardless of whether their display conditions are met.
- Inside of a calculation (or display condition, etc...) `if()` statements on the other hand **do** "short circuit logic", meaning that the branch that isn't used won't be executed at all.

  - This is also true of the logic operators `and` and `or`

Example:

There is a hidden value with the calculate expression:
`long_expensive_calc()`

Setting the expression instead to

`if( #form/time_to_go = 'yes' , '', long_expensive_calc())`

will prevent the "expensive" portion from running until the `time_to_go` is set to `yes`.