# Does function order of operations in CommCare HQ affect efficiency of execution on the mobile device?

Tags: commcare

I have a caselist filter that is taking a long time to execute and am wondering if I can do anything with the if/and/or <= >= statements to help things run more efficiently ("faster").
The formula is essenstially:

`((((today() - resident_under2_dob) > 6) and ((today() - resident_under2_dob) < 46) and (hhcl1_satisfied != '1')) 
or
((((today() - resident_under2_dob) div 30.25) > 6) and (((today() - resident_under2_dob) div 30.25) < 9) and (hhcl2_satisfied != '1')) 
or
((((today() - resident_under2_dob) div 30.25) > 24) and (((today() - resident_under2_dob) div 30.25) < 27) and (hhcl3_satisfied != '1')) 
or
((((today() - estimated_dob) div 30.25) > 24) and (((today() - estimated_dob) div 30.25) < 27) and (hhcl3_satisfied != '1')))
)`

There's actually an additional 'and' but it references an instance, so I want to ask that in a seperate question so we don't cross the streams.

Comment: Based on feedback here I add a leading "and" so only cases under the max age enter the population sorting listed above, that seems to have knocked about 30 seconds off the original 2 minutes.  I then also noticed all the "div" processes that were happening (to change days to months) so I took those out and dropped about 30 seconds that way also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(answer and big caveat from another source)

**1) an equation in the "wrong" side of an 'if' statement will not be entered**

**2) the second half of an 'and' statement will not be executed if the first test was false**

**3) the second half of an 'or' statement will not be executed if the first test was true.**

*However, it may not help anyway, for reasons laid out here:*

When we parse a form, we break down XPath Calculations/Relevancies/etc into what we call a set of Triggerrables. These triggerables are an XPath Expression (IE: "if(/data/do_calculates, complex_xpath, '')") which has some outcome on a set of targets (IE: /data/myval = the outcome). Each of which is a single expression with multiple "Targets". If two questions have the same relevancy expression, they share one triggerable

We then go through all of the expressions in our triggerables and find their triggers , so *any* path where a change which would result in a change in the outcome of the triggerable. Note that each of these triggers can be in a "floating context". So if you take the expression:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_id = instance('mylocations')/locations/location[@id = current()/../@repeat_id]/@parent_id]/last_visited_by
```

That expression is triggered by whichever nodes are relevant to whatever its current()/../@repeat_id evaluates to, which might change if it is re-used, so we need to keep track of a lot of information about the *full context* of what expressions trigger an update, not just, say, "/data/myvalue"

Finally, we make a run where we build a graph of dependencies between the triggers, and we build a final ordering of which triggerables being executed in which orders will ensure that we touch every triggerable if needed, without going in the wrong order.

So when we *change* a value, we:

First walk the graph identifying all recursive dependencies which might be triggered by the change. IE: /data/a might update Triggers "1, 3, and 10, and each of them might update 2, 11, and 5"

Now we've collected a comprehensive list of the triggers that might update. At this point, these are context free, because we can't know until evaluation which specific instance of element_2 is going to be triggered by `/data/element_2[@id = /data/element_1[id = #form_something]/id/value` until we've already done the element_1 eval, we just know that it *might*, that means we can't test whether element_2 has *changed* since the last eval),

Finally we do one pass through our canonical list of triggerables (Which is much larger in the form where they aren't blank) and we have to actually prod the triggerable and see if the trigger meets its pattern. If so, we actually run the triggerable expression.

Answer (score 0):

`and`, `or`, and `if()` all do short circuit as outlined in more detail in the answer to this question.

[Prevent slow calculate conditions from firing when the form is opened](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103706/prevent-slow-calculate-conditions-from-firing-when-the-form-is-opened)